# Sequential CSS selectors not being applied

Tags: css

Hello people of the interwebs.

I have the following CSS in a React project (imported with `import App.css`

```
.xBackground {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(/static/xBg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    top: 0;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.xBackground  {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 54% !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    background-position: center left !important;
}
```

The second selector's style is not being applied at all.

Comment: well you have an opening tag for a comment there `/*` but not a closing one, so it turns your css invalid. Or this is just some 'copy-paste' error ?

Comment: Which can even be noticed in the code colorification in the Stack-Snippet and in any other decent code editor.

Comment: Error during editing for stackOverflow. sorry

Comment: all this CSS is imported from 1 file ? or you import the first styles and then try to overwrite some of them manually ?

Comment: @MihaiT all of the CSS is in the same file. The problem remains even when placing them directly below each other as above

Comment: Well. If they are in the same file. And you can edit the file. Why don't you edit the first style ? Why add a second one ?.

Comment: @MihaiT the end goal is to override the first style later depending on screen width.

Comment: Look into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: the you should use media queries for that.  for example. `@media only screen (max-width: 768px) { /* add here the styles to overwrite */ } `

Comment: @MihaiT The idea is to use media queries and the original code reflects that, however, the styles are not being overridden when in a media query block either.

Comment: You can try to use a more specific selector. for eg `#grandparent .parent .xBackground  { } `

Answer (score 0):

There are two spaces between the end of the selector and the bracket. Removing the additional space solves the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that was the problem ? https://jsfiddle.net/4ocben0g/ it doesn't seem to matter. and i never saw something like that causing a css problem.

Comment: It seems to be a project-specific thing. I'm not sure why the spaces matter but it fixes the problem.